# WinSCP How to check for directory existence before creating it on FTP server?

Tags: winscp

**Trying to automate via Jenkins**:  Transfer files from Local Windows directory to FTP directory via WinSCP console scripting.

**Problem statement**: Need to check whether a folder exists on FTP server before initiating upload.

This is the code I'm trying to execute via `winscp /script=abc.txt`

**abc.txt** as follows:

```
open ftp://xyz
mkdir /Server_folder/test_folder/ABC
put FROM_LOCAL_PATH TO_SERVER_PATH
bye
```

Comment: you can use `stat /Server_folder/test_folder/ABC` and use `errorlevel` to determine the existence. See [this link](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_checking_file_existence) scroll down to the example batch file.

Comment: Well, are you using a plugin or is it your code? If you are doing mkdir, just use -p.

Comment: @hakamairi I'm using code. and mkdir -p <path> doesn't work

Comment: what's the error you get?

Comment: Unknown switch 'p'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you clarified you are using WinSCP scripting console

```
option batch continue
mkdir some_dir
option batch abort
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this via WinSCP console on FTP server. It's not using IF command.

Comment: That makes your question very far from being clear. Updated my answer

Comment: Made changes in the question accordingly